# Spanning set for $\mathbb{R}^4$

Tags: linear-algebra

Small question:

Let $A= \text{span}\{(1,0,0,-1), (0,1,-1,0)\}$ and $B=\text{span}\{(1, 0, 0, 1), (0,1, 1, 0)\}$. Does $\mathbb{R}^4=B+A$? I thought it did, but computationally I can't work it out.

Also, I'm looking to directly show if any vector in $\mathbb{R}^4$ can be written as a vector in $B+A$--very basic methods.

Comment: Write down an equation that expresses your last sentence for an arbitrary element of $\mathbb R^4$. This will give you a system of linear equations to solve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:
$$
\det \begin{bmatrix}
1&0&1&0\\
0&1&0&1\\
0&-1&0&1\\
-1&0&1&0
\end{bmatrix}=-4
$$
this implies that for any vector $[a,b,c,d]^T$ there are four numbers $x,y,z,t$ such that $xv_1+yv_2+zv_3+tv_4=[a,b,c,d]^T$ where $v_1,v_2,v_3,v_4$ are the four columns of the matrix.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: are these 4 vectors linearly independent?

Comment: I actually want to do it directly. Technically I can't use that notion explicitly for what I want

Comment: Nevertheless my hint is useful even if you want to do it directly. Take a linear combination of these 4 vectors. The part consisting of the 1st two will be in $A$, the part consisting of 2nd two will be from $B$.